# Roots of $\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=b$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am trying to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of a probability distribution, and while I don't believe I can get a closed form expression, I would like to get an idea of the general shape of the distribution. The Laplace transform is a nice rational function, however, the roots of the denominator are the inverse (I mean $1/z$) of the following 
$$\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=b$$

where $b>1$ and real. What can be said about the zeros of the polynomial? Are they all real, what is their degeneracy? Are there any $b$ derived bounds on the roots (i.e. do they all fall in a circle of radius $2b^{1/n}$ for example-- I know it is not true, just giving an example)?

Comment: I just tried it in Alpha for several cases.  You can see it with n=8, b=4 at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28z%5E8-1%29%2F%28z-1%29%3D4  The roots seem to lie on an approximate circle, one real for n even, two (one each side of zero) for n odd.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The expression $$\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}-b = 1-b+z+z^2+\cdots+z^n$$ can be thought of as the $n^{\text{th}}$ partial sum of the power series for $\frac{1}{1-z}-b$, whose circle of convergence is the unit circle.  By Jentzsch's theorem, every point on the unit circle will thus be a limit point of the zeros of these partial sums.

Here is a plot of all of the zeros for $n=3,4,\ldots,70$ with $b = 4$. The unit circle is shown in blue.

[image: zeros]

It appears that there are no limit points outside of the circle of convergence, which I believe follows from the fact that the reciprocal polynomials of the partial sums at the top of this answer converge to $1/(1-z)$ inside the unit circle, which has no zeros.

Also, there is one limit point inside of the circle of convergence at $z=(b-1)/b$, which is the lone zero of the limit function of the partial sums which lies within the circle of convergence.

(The above should be read in the context of [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), which essentially says that any zero of the limit function which is inside the circle of convergence will be a limit point of the partial sums.)

Lastly, if I had to guess the rate of convergence of the zeros to the unit circle, I would say they approach at about $O(1/n)$ based on working with similar problems.

Comment: I wish I could +more than 1 for this